# Implement completion handler lambda in Android java

Tags: java, android, kotlin, lambda

I have a method in Kotlin which has a callback function like below,

```
@JvmStatic
fun getContents(callBack:(filePath:String,name:String,expiry:Int,metadata:String) -> Unit){

}
```

I can access this function in kotlin, but how can I access this from a Java class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have many ways, I'll list some of them below and it should help direct you to build it the way you want.

### Use case #1 - function inside a kotlin file

If you have the following kotlin file for example: `Content.kt`

The content of the file will be something like:

```kotlin
fun getContents(callBack: (filePath: String, name: String, expiry: Int, metadata: String) -> Unit) {
}
```

Then from Java you can call it like the following:

```java
ContentKt.getContents((filePath, name, expiry, metadata) -> {
  return Unit.INSTANCE;
});
```

### Use case #2 - function inside a kotlin file, changing the jvm name

You can also specify `@file:JvmName(...)` if you want to remove the `kt` that is added to the file name or if you want to give it any other logical name:

```kotlin
@file:JvmName("Content")

package test

fun getContents(callBack: (filePath: String, name: String, expiry: Int, metadata: String) -> Unit) {
}
```

Then you can call it like that:

```java
Content.getContents((filePath, name, expiry, metadata) -> {
    return Unit.INSTANCE;
});
```

### Use case #3 - static function inside companion object or in an object

Given the following kotlin class:

```kotlin
class Content {
  companion object {
    @JvmStatic
    fun getContents(callBack: (filePath: String, name: String, expiry: Int, metadata: String) -> Unit) {
    }
  }
}
```

Or the following object:

```kotlin
object Content {
  @JvmStatic
  fun getContents(callBack: (filePath: String, name: String, expiry: Int, metadata: String) -> Unit) {
  }
}
```

You will access it like that via Java:

```java
Content.getContents((filePath, name, expiry, metadata) -> {
    return Unit.INSTANCE;
});
```